# How to retrieve specific records from a ResultSet

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming i have variable $row that contains the result from this query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'keyword'
```

I am implementing lazy scroll which loads more content as the user scrolls down the page. I will not want to be sending queries to the server any time the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. I want to keep on displaying data from `$row` using something like `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` whenever the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. Please, any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can either send the whole result to the client and use javascript for the pagination (so client side logic) or you keep the result in memory (session or in-memory-database like redis) to read from it. The first obviously is easier to implement and more efficient, _unless_ the dataset gets bigger...

Answer (score -1):

For a server, lazy scroll is no different from the usual pagination. Neither there is whatever "result set" that sits on the server and waits for a request.

So from the client just send a regular request with the required offset and on the server make a regular query with limit and offset. That's all.